# Sort Sales of Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Please do not ban, I have read other similar questions but they dont work out for me.
I Created a Pivot Table but cant manage to sort it by sales ("Ventas") .

```
'Try to sort (Not Working)
With ptTable
    .PivotFields("Ventas").AutoSort xlDescending, "Total Ventas"
End With
```

```
Sub CrearTablaDinamicaaaa()
    Dim ws_Source As Worksheet
    Dim ws_Dest As Worksheet
    Dim ptCache As PivotCache
    Dim ptTable As PivotTable
    Dim rangoDatos As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ptTableName As String
    
    
    
    Set ws_Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base Ventas Asistidos")
    Set ws_Dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deporte")
    ptTableName = "TablaDinamicaVentas"

    ' Define range where to place the Pivot Table
    lastRow = ws_Source.Cells(ws_Source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rangoDatos = ws_Source.Range("A1:L" & lastRow)

    ' Crear un Pivot Cache 
    Set ptCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rangoDatos)

    ' Crete Pivot Table
    Set ptTable = ptCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws_Dest.Range("H40"), TableName:=ptTableName)

    ' Configure Pivot Table
    With ptTable
      
        'Filter
        .PivotFields("División").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("División").Position = 1

        'Filter
        .PivotFields("Semana").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("Semana").Position = 2

        'Rows
        .PivotFields("SKU").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("SKU").Position = 1

        'Create Values of "Ventas" (Sales)
        With .PivotFields("Ventas")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum
            .Position = 1
            .Name = "Total Ventas"
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Refresh
ptTable.RefreshTable


'Try to sort (Not Working)
With ptTable
    .PivotFields("Ventas").AutoSort xlDescending, "Total Ventas"
End With



' Refresh
ptTable.RefreshTable


End Sub
```

Comment: "cant manage" and "not working" tells us nothing. What happens or doesn't happen that you are not expecting or expecting. If you pause the code before the 2nd `RefreshTable` has the table sorted?

Comment: Im expecting the PivotFields "Ventas" to autoSort it self, but it dosent do anything.
If I pause the the code before the 2nd refreshtable it does not sort it self

Comment: You need to sort the **SKU** field (not the Ventas field) by the Total Ventas field.

Comment: Thats it, as always thank you Rory!